# Why does only the sound for turning off the flashlight play?

Tags: unity, c#

This script is supposed to play a sound when I turn on the flashlight sprite and a different sound when I turn it off, but for some reason it's only playing the second sound.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class flashlightonoffsound : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool flashlightisoff = false;

    public AudioSource flashlightsound1;

    public AudioSource flashlightsound2;
  
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            if (flashlightisoff)
            {
                flashlightsound1.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                flashlightsound2.Play();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: also idk why but the some of the code isn't in the code box when i post it for some reason but its fine you can still understand it

Comment: just select it all, and press the `{}` button above the text box, that'll help  =)

Comment: I don't want to sound obvious, but have you checked that you don't have the same sound assigned to both variables in the inspector?

Comment: yeah i made sure

Comment: Where do you change the value of `flashlightisoff`?

Comment: i have a seperate script for turning the flashlight on and off. should I show you it?

Comment: Yes, I have a feeling that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: one thing you could try, is under `if (flashlightisoff)` add the line: `flashlightisoff = false` and under `else` add the line: `flashlightisoff = true`.  it depends on your flashlight code, though.  I'm guessing that flashlightisoff is always false, so it's always playing the 2nd sound.

Comment: If that code is required to test this code and see it work as desired, then yes, it should be included in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would suggest not to use 2 AudioSources. That causes a lot of confusion. Instead use only one audiosource for one game object, and switch between audioClips:

```
public AudioClip clip1;
public AudioClip clip2;
```

and then somewhere in your logic you play the clip:

```
myAudioSource.PlayOneShot(clip1); // or clip2 ....
```

Second make sure you are changing value of *flashlightisoff* correctly. For example you maybe changing it ok, but next frame it reverts back (which often is mistake when people are using *Input.GetKeyDown*).
You can track value of your variable like that:

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("value:" + flashlightisoff );
}
```

then watch console for what happens with your variable every frame, and you will know where fault is.

Comment: it worked thanks ShoulO!

Comment: Glad to hear that  !